# Proving that three events are mutually independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Suppose that:
>
> - the events $A$ and $B\cap C$ are independent.
> - the events $B$ and $A\cap C$ are independent.
> - the events $C$ and $A\cap B$ are independent.
> - the events $A$ and $B\cup C$ are independent.
> - $P(A),P(B),P(C)$ are nonzero.
>
> Prove that $A,B,C$ are mutually independent.

I've noticed that $P(A\cap B \cap C)=P(A)P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(A\cap C)=P(C)P(A\cap B)$.

What then? I'm new to probability, and I may be missing some standard trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$  P(A \cap (B\cup C)) = P(A \cap B)+ P(A \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$

$P(A \cap (B\cup C)) = P(A ) P(B\cup C))= P(A )(P(B)+P(C)-P(B \cap C))$

$\Rightarrow 
P(A \cap B)+ P(A \cap C)= P(A )(P(B)+P(C))$

$ \Rightarrow 
P(B)P(C)( P(A \cap B)+ P(A \cap C))= P(A ) P(B)P(C) (P(B)+P(C)) $

$ \Rightarrow
P(A \cap B\cap C)= P(A ) P(B)P(C) $

Comment: Great job! How do you prove next that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ ?

Comment: $ P(A) P(B\cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) $